# Не добавляется пользовательский шрифт в Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Доброго дня. Пытаюсь кодить на C#, с использованием Visual Studio + xamarin. Естественно кросс-платформенная разработка. Захотелось использовать свой шрифт в Label. Начал с инструкции с официального сайта для Android. Но ничего так и не изменилось. При этом нет даже ошибок, программа собирается, запускается на отладку, но шрифт идет по умолчанию. Использовал шрифты только .ttf. Файл шрифта добавил в папку Assets, связывание указал как AndroidResource. Собственно, может кто знает, в чем тут дело? Может не правильно просто указал имя шрифта? Или надо писать полный путь в тегах? Нашел пару статей по этому поводу в сети, но там подобные вещи делают через переопределение рендера элементов управления, что, для столь простой операции, кажется избыточным. Вот код XAML. 
`<Label Text="Hello Forms with XAML">
    <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <OnPlatform.iOS></OnPlatform.iOS>
            <OnPlatform.Android>Lobster-Regular.ttf#Lobster-regular</OnPlatform.Android>
            <OnPlatform.WinPhone></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>`
На сайте утверждается, что он должен работать, но у меня так и не запустилcя.

Снова вернулся к этой теме.
Немного побив в бубен и покурив мануалы ни черта там не нашел. Зато нажимая кнопки в случайном порядке выяснил интересную вещь. У меня скачано 2 проекта для работы со шрифтами с GitHub и оф. сайта. Там все работает, причем работают и те шрифты, которые я хотел поставить. В моем же проекте ничего. Так вот когда я в работающем проекте испортил имя файла в блоке

`<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <OnPlatform.iOS></OnPlatform.iOS>
            <OnPlatform.Android>Lobster-Regular.ttf#Lobster-regular</OnPlatform.Android>
            <OnPlatform.WinPhone></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
        </OnPlatform>`
решение стало падать с ошибкой нет такого файла на этапе отладки, компиляция проходит нормально. В проектах, созданных на моей машине подобного не происходит, т.е. как я понимаю, программа даже не пытается подключить этот шрифт. Вот и с чем такое может быть связанно? В каких настройках прописано, что FontFamily отказывается получать свой параметр?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы не указали Build Action для файлов

[image: Окно с настройками]

И используйте Android Asset для Android (Файлы шрифтов должны располагаться в папке Assets)

Для ios вам необходимо добавить названия файлов (не шрифтов) в plist. А так же 
поменяйте Build Action на BundleResource. В Xaml разметке используйте название шрифта (не файла)

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что все это я пробовал! И папки правильные, и имена шрифтов. С apple кстати проблем то нет, шрифт меняется на ура. А вот в андроиде все делаю по книге - ни черта не получается. Я создал свой рендер для метки, но это просто костыль, для каждого объекта с текстом свой рендер писать замучаешься